# Show that $f(z)=1/z^2$is not uniformly continuous for $0\lt Rez\lt 1/2$ but is uniformly continuous for $1/2\lt Rez\lt 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, continuity

Show that $f(z)=1/z^2$is not uniformly continuous for $0\lt Rez\lt 1/2$ but is uniformly continuous for $1/2\lt Rez\lt 1$.

To prove the first assertion, I came up with sequences $x_n=1/n, y_n=1/(n-1)$ for $n \ge 3$. Then $|x_n-y_n| \to 0$ but $|f(x_n)-f(y_n)| \to \infty$ so the function is not uniformly continuous on $0 \gt Rez \gt 1/2$. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to show this without using sequences, like the $\epsilon-\delta$ method.

Meanwhile, I'm having trouble showing the second part. I need to show that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$, there is a $\delta \gt 0$ such that whenever $|x-y| \lt \delta$, $|1/x^2-1/y^2|\lt \epsilon$. From the condition $1/2 \lt Rez \lt 1$, I got, $|1/x^2-1/y^2|=|x-y||x+y|/|x^2||y^2|\le 4\delta |x+y|$. But I cannot show that this final part is $\lt \epsilon$. How may I prove this? I would appreciate any solution.

Comment: If you don't mind using a strong result, you can also directly use Heine's theorem for the second part. But I think the point of the question was to do it withoud that kind of stuff.

Comment: Isn't it enough that $|f'(z)|$ is bounded for $z \ge \frac12$?

Comment: @msteve How is $|x|+|y| \le Re(x)+Re(y)$? Isn't it the opposite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \{z : 1/2 < \operatorname{Re}z < 1\}$. For all $z,w\in X$, $|zw| = |z|  \ge \operatorname{Re}(z) > 1/2$ and $|w| \ge \operatorname{Re}(w) > 1/2$, hence

$$|f(z) - f(w)| = \left|\left(\frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{w}\right)\left(\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{w}\right)\right| \le \frac{|z - w|}{|zw|}\left(\frac{1}{|z|} + \frac{1}{|w|}\right) < 16|z - w|.$$

So if $\epsilon > 0$, choosing $\delta = \epsilon/16$ will make $|f(z) - f(w)| < \epsilon$ for all $z,w \in X$ such that $|z - w| < \delta$. Therefore, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Let $Y = \{z : 0 < \operatorname{Re}(z) < 1/2\}$. Set $\epsilon = 7$. If $0 < \delta \le 1$, set $z = \delta/3$ and $w = \delta/4$. Then $z,w\in Y$ with $|z - w|  = \delta/12 < \delta$ and $|f(z) - f(w)| = 7/\delta^2 \ge \epsilon$. If $\delta > 1$, setting $z = 1/(3\delta)$ and $y = 1/(4\delta)$ will make $z, w\in Y$, $|z - w| = 1/(12\delta) < \delta$, and $|f(z) - f(w)| = 7\delta^2 \ge \epsilon$. Hence, $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $Y$.